# CTE : looping data input every 15 days| SQL, SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have this test code from the guides here that I modified for test practice.
What I'm trying to achieve in this code is for it to loop the input based on a certain number, and it will loop with a 15 day gap.

Scenario: I will set the looping into **5 times**. And the start date of the loop is **08/15/2019**

So, the data that should be inputted is **08/15/2019**, **08/30/2019**, **09/15/2019**, **09/30/2019**, **10/15/2019** (Assuming that all dates are in 30 days.)

```
DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE ([Month] date, [Data 1] INT, [Data 2] INT, [Data 3] INT);
WITH MYLOOP AS (
    SELECT CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE) AS [date], 100 as [Data 3]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]), [Data 3]=[Data 3]+1
    FROM MYLOOP
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]) <  CAST('2022-01-01' AS DATE) )
INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month], [Data 1], [Data 2], [Data 3])
SELECT LEFT([date],10) as [Month], 100 AS [Data 1], 100 AS [Data 2], [Data 3]
FROM MYLOOP
SELECT * FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

This is the guide that I got based on that scenario.
My problem now is that I'm having a hard time implementing the 2 SQL Queries into 1.

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (YourDate int, valuex int,tests int)
insert into @YourTable VALUES ('100',5,11)
;WITH AllNumbers AS
(SELECT 1 AS Number, 100 AS [value]
UNION ALL
SELECT Number+1, [value]=[value]+1
FROM AllNumbers
WHERE Number<=15-1 )
SELECT 
YourDate, valuex, tests
FROM @YourTable        y
INNER JOIN AllNumbers  a ON 1=1
```

This is what I got so far.

```
DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE ([Month] date, [Data 1] INT, [Data 2] INT, [Data 3] INT);
WITH MYLOOP AS (
    SELECT CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE) AS [date], 1 as [Data 2], 100 as [Data 3]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [date]), [Data 2]+1, [Data 3]=[Data 3]+1
    FROM MYLOOP
    WHERE  [Data 2] < 7 )
INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month], [Data 1], [Data 2], [Data 3])
SELECT LEFT([date],10) as [Month], 100 AS [Data 1], [Data 2], [Data 3]
FROM MYLOOP
SELECT * FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

> How do is set to to trigger, or **add every 15 days**, and not every **1 month(30 days)**?

May I ask for your assistance on this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for 5 dates only from your input date, this following script will work-

> Input date must need to be 15 or 30 of a month

```
DECLARE @st_dt DATE = '08/15/2019'
DECLARE @prev_dt DATE
DECLARE @LC INT =0
DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE ([Month] date)

WHILE @LC < 5
BEGIN

    IF @LC = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month]) VALUES(@st_dt)
        SET @prev_dt = @st_dt
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN   
        IF DATEPART(DD,@prev_dt) = 15
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month]) VALUES(DATEADD(DD,(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,@prev_dt) = 2 THEN 13 ELSE 15 END) ,@prev_dt))

            SET @prev_dt = DATEADD(DD,(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,@prev_dt) = 2 THEN 13 ELSE 15 END) ,@prev_dt)
        END

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month]) 
            VALUES(DATEADD(DD,(15-DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(MM,1,@prev_dt))),DATEADD(MM,1,@prev_dt)))

            SET @prev_dt = DATEADD(DD,(15-DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(MM,1,@prev_dt))),DATEADD(MM,1,@prev_dt))
        END
    END


    SET @LC = @LC + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

Output is-

```
Month
2019-08-15
2019-08-30
2019-09-15
2019-09-30
2019-10-15
```

Now, If only adding +15 days with previous date can satisfy your requirement, this is easy and this following script will work for you-

```
DECLARE @st_dt DATE = '8/01/2019'
DECLARE @prev_dt DATE
DECLARE @LC INT =0
DECLARE @MYTESTTABLE TABLE ([Month] date)

WHILE @LC < 5
BEGIN

    IF @LC = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month]) VALUES(@st_dt)
        SET @prev_dt = @st_dt
    END

    ELSE
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @MYTESTTABLE ([Month]) VALUES(DATEADD(DD,15,@prev_dt))
        SET @prev_dt = DATEADD(DD,15,@prev_dt)
    END


    SET @LC = @LC + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @MYTESTTABLE
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you. Now all I have to do is study this and implement in my actual database. Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome @pjustindaryll. Its always nice to hear that code helped :)

Comment: I have 1 question though, what if the date is different? will it still follow the **date+15** format?

Comment: Nope. There will be unwanted output. What actually you required in case of different date like 08/13/2019? if you explain, logic can be implemented.

Comment: What I'm trying to implement is it will just add **15 days** on the date inputted, for example **08-26-2019** as inputted date, we will just add **15 days** on that date on every loop.

Comment: Allow me some time, get back to you soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198467/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-pjustindaryll).

Comment: is this the ancient coding style :D

Answer (score 2):

This is the CTE version

```
-- straight 15 days addition

declare @startdate date = '2019-08-15'
declare @loop smallint = 15

;with cte_count as (
 select 0 ctr
 union all
 select ctr + 1 from cte_count
 where ctr < @loop-1
)
select dateadd(day,ctr*15,x.newdate) [Date] from cte_count
cross join
 (select @startdate newdate) x
```

--- below shows 15th day and end of month

```
declare @startdate date = '2019-08-15'
declare @loop smallint = 50

;with cte_count as (
 select 0 ctr
 union all
 select ctr + 1 from cte_count
 where ctr < @loop-1
)
select 
distinct 
cast(iif(day(dateadd(day,ctr*15,newdate))<=15,
 dateadd(day,14,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, eomonth(dateadd(day,ctr*15,newdate))), 0))
,eomonth(dateadd(day,ctr*15,newdate))) as date)
from cte_count
cross join
 (select @startdate newdate) x
```